# Why is the TTFB of requests 5 times longer when a new TCP session is created on Apache?

Tags: web-server, apache-2.4, web

When testing on an image served with `apache`, I have noticed that when a new session is created the:

`Waiting (TTFB)`: `1.09s`
`Initial connection + SSL handshake`: `370ms`
`DNS Lookup`: `165ms`

But then with a persistent connection the following:

`Waiting (TTFB)`: `187ms`
`Content Download`: `4ms`

So we have found on average the `TTFB` is 5 times longer on new connections, non-persistent.
Is this normal?

Side question: Why does it do a new DNS lookup only when there is a new connection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is normal that non-persistent connections take longer to send first byte of data.

This is because the IP address has to be resolved from the DNS, the TCP connection has to be set up, then the SSL/TLS layer has to be initialized, and only after that actual data can be sent.

DNS lookup is not performed on a persistent connection, because there already is an active TCP connection between the client and server IP addresses Therefore there is no need to resolve the domain name to an IP address.

Regarding Apache `KeepAlive` and `KeepAliveTimeout` directives. `KeepAlive` specifies if Apache should keep client connections open for subsequent requests for other resources on the same site. These are persistent connections, where one avoids the delays mentioned previously.

However, keeping connections alive use resources on the server, since each TCP connection takes memory to maintain the state. Therefore with `KeepAliveTimeout` directive one can specify how long an idle connection is kept open before the web server closes it. This also makes it harder for malicious clients to exhaust server resources by opening HTTP connections and keeping them open indefinitely.

`MaxKeepaliveRequests` means how many requests are allowed per single KeepAlive connection. I cannot imagine a situation where one would want to limit the number of requests. For best performance, I would use `0`, that is unlimited number of requests.

These directives are related to HTTP(S) sessions between the visitor and web server. PHP-FPM is not related to this interface. However, similar keepalive mechanism is available in nginx for FastCGI interface. I don't know if a similar mechanism is available in Apache.